# matrix using pointers c++ without dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

So i have an assigment that would read a matrix using pointers and show it using pointers also i wanna know why it always add a row where is exactly the mistake and it doesnt show the matrix also thnks

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int Mat[50][50],N,M;
    int (*ptr)[50][50];
    cout<<"number of lignes : ";
    cin>>N;
    cout<<"number of rows : : ";
    cin>>M;
    ptr=&Mat;
    
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
     {
        for (int j=0 ; j<M ;j++)
         {
              cout<<"fill the matrix [" <<i<<","<<j<< "] : " ;
              cin>>*ptr[i][j];  
         }
     }
    
    for (int i=0 ; i<N ; i++ )
     {
        for (int j=0 ; j<M ; j++)
        {
            cout<<*ptr[i][j] <<" ";
        }
        cout<"/n";
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you open your C++ textbook to the chapter that explains operator precedences, which operator, unary `*` or `[]` does your textbook say has higher precedence, and what do you do when you want a different order of precedence?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than creating them with default values and immediately overwriting the defaults. In this case, that means changing `int (*ptr)[50][50] ... ptr = &Mat;` to `int (*ptr)[50][50] = &Mat;`. Also, those 50s should be defined by a constant, e.g., `const int dim = 50; int Mat[dim][dim];`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is here

```
cin>>*ptr[i][j];
```

that should be

```
cin>>(*ptr)[i][j];
```

and the same error here

```
cout<<*ptr[i][j];
```

that should be

```
cout<<(*ptr)[i][j];
```

But why are you using `ptr` why not just use `Mat` instead?

```
cin>>Mat[i][j];
cout<<Mat[i][j];
```

What do you think is the benefit of using a pointer to your matrix, why not just use the matrix itself?

Note that your code isn't a matrix **using** pointers, its a pointer to a matrix, which is not the same thing at all. So maybe you've misunderstood what you have been asked to do.

Comment: @WalidWalid Glad it helps, but I have a feeling that you have been asked to write a different kind of matrix. Think carefully about the difference between a matrix that uses pointers, and a pointer to a matrix. They are not the same thing.

Comment: No it's my fault they asked for a pointer to a matrix (and i know that the matrix is a pointer itself) but the assignement asked for this i dont know why

Comment: And btw what is the diff between a matrix use pointers and pointer to a matrix ? I'm curios to know